# SQL get unique month year combos

Tags: sql, unique, distinct

```
SELECT     MONTH(sessionStart) AS Expr1, YEAR(sessionStart) AS Expr2
FROM         tblStatSessions
WHERE     (projectID = 187)
GROUP BY sessionStart
```

This returns:

> 11  |  2010
>
> 11  |  2010
>
> 11  |  2010
>
> 12  |  2010
>
> 12  |  2010

But I need it to only return each instance once, IE:

> 11   |  2010
>
> 12   |  2010

If that makes sense!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following should be what you want:

```
SELECT     MONTH(sessionStart) AS Expr1, YEAR(sessionStart) AS Expr2
FROM         tblStatSessions
WHERE     (projectID = 187)
GROUP BY MONTH(sessionStart), YEAR(sessionStart)
```

in general you need to `group by` every non-aggregate column that you are selecting. Some DBMSs, such as Oracle, enforce this, i.e. not doing so results in an error rather than 'strange' query execution.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT     MONTH(sessionStart) AS Expr1, YEAR(sessionStart) AS Expr2
FROM         tblStatSessions
WHERE     (projectID = 187)
GROUP BY Expr1
```